# Change top color on Drawer widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering how I can change the top-most color seen when my `Drawer` is open?

In the image below you can see two arrows, 1 and 2. Arrow 2 points at my main screen which is my `primaryColor` and is shown correctly on all screens except on my drawer.

I'm trying to have an all white drawer and want to remove the grey color from the top.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may solve your issue, by removing padding of ListView.

```
drawer: new Drawer(
  child: new ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    children: <Widget>[
       ......
    ]
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Drawer with SafeArea widget

Answer (score 0):

I also had this my app,
I changed ListView to Column and it worked. Usually, we don't keep too much in Drawer so Column worked for me.

```
drawer: new Drawer(
child: new Column(                  ///here change ListView to Column
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
children: <Widget>[
   ......
]
```

),
),